# War location on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very new to aws and have created an instance using EC2 console through the UI. I have deployed a war file on that instance. I want to access my installed war file through putty. I am able to connect to my aws instance using putty but i am not able to locate my war file which is running on my instance on aws linux.

Help needed.

Comment: You can use "find" command to locate your war file. Execute find / -name "*.war" will list all the war file location. Hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I checked mine using Hussain's method:

```
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/yourWarFileName
```

so try to do  a:

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat'yourTomcatVersionNumber'>/webapps/yourWarFileName
```

Hope that helps.